Bedrock Knowledge Base Data source semantic chunking error
I have a CSV that I got from my database within Glue (dataset)
When I use it as a data source for KB, customising my chunking and parsing using FM Claude 3 Sonnet V1 and semantic chunking, however when I try to sync, then I get this error:
File body text exceeds size limit of 1000000 for semantic chunking.

Have you happened to see this error before?


Provide the statement where error occurred. or stack trace

this error occurred when I ran a sync operation in kb's data source
Encountered error: File body text exceeds size limit of 1000000 for semantic chunking. [Files: appointment/part-00001-b9e386db-f5fe-4f54-ae98-9413b930d328-c000.csv, appointment/part-00000-b9e386db-f5fe-4f54-ae98-9413b930d328-c000.csv]. Call to Customer Source did not succeed.

Looks like you are exceeding model context window. Claude 3 sonnet have 200k token context window. try to split the files and try chunking. Your two files are probably generating more than 1000k .

Would splitting it into tiny files be a way to handle this error? I'll try anyway, thanks mate

yes splitting works for me - albeit, I have only split the file in a very crude way; I do not know if it will improve the results or not; I'm working  with large text files, with context at the start of the document - so splitting in half doesn't seem like the correct approach for me.
